# AttributeError: Element instance has no attribute '__float__' in Python

Tags: python, xml, django, minidom

I get this error when I run my script

```
AttributeError: Element instance has no attribute '__float__'
```

My code looks like this:

```
def populate():
    parsedfiles = minidom.parse('C:\Users\User\Downloads\New folder\StreetTrees_ArbutusRidge.xml')
    treelist = parsedfiles.getElementsByTagName('StreetTree')
    for alltrees in treelist:
        treeId = alltrees.getAttribute('TreeID')
        neighbourhood = alltrees.getElementsByTagName('NeighbourhoodName')
        commonName = alltrees.getElementsByTagName('CommonName')
        diameter = alltrees.getElementsByTagName('Diameter')[0]
        diameter = float(diameter)
        streetNumber = alltrees.getElementsByTagName('CivicNumber')
        street = alltrees.getElementsByTagName('StdStreet')
        lat = 0
        lon = 0
        add_tree(treeId=treeId, neighbourhood=neighbourhood, commonName=commonName,
                 diameter=diameter, streetNumber=streetNumber, street=street, lat=0, lon=0)
```

I think I'm misinterpreting the `diameter` but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diameter` is a DOM `Element`:

```
diameter = alltrees.getElementsByTagName('Diameter')[0]
```

It is not directly convertable to a float, because that's not textual data; you probably want the text *contained in the element*:

```
diameter = alltrees.getElementsByTagName('Diameter')[0]
diameter = float(diameter.firstChild.nodeValue)
```

Note that the W3C DOM is rather a pain to work with; you may want to look into the more Pythonic [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead:

```
parsedfiles = etree.parse(r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\New folder\StreetTrees_ArbutusRidge.xml')
for alltrees in parsedfiles.findall('.//StreetTree'):
    treeId = alltrees. attrib['TreeID']
    neighbourhood = alltrees.findall('NeighbourhoodName')
    commonName = alltrees.findall('CommonName')
    diameter = float(alltrees.find('Diameter').text)
    streetNumber = alltrees.findall('CivicNumber')
    street = alltrees.findall('StdStreet')
    add_tree(treeId=treeId, neighbourhood=neighbourhood, commonName=commonName,
             diameter=diameter, streetNumber=streetNumber, street=street,
             lat=0, lon=0)
```

where I am assuming that the various elements you are looking for are directly contained in the `<StreetTree>` element.